# To Populate data from a column in excel based on a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have list of students in one column and their scores in another column 
I need to populate the names of the student who have scores less than 70%
Marks in single column in a different work sheets.

Comment: Can you just use the `Auto Filter`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF formula in the new sheet to populate the column. Lets assume your names are in column A and their scores are in column B. You could use something like -

```
=IF([Book1]Sheet1!$B1<0.7,"Under 70%","")
```

And then you can drag this formula down. This will mark those with scores under 70% with text that says "Under 70%" and will leave the cell blank if above 70%.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what what i wanted is to populate a separate list of names and save it in a different worksheet in a single column

Comment: You could use an IF statement in a separate sheet and say IF("test score"<.70,"name of person","") and then filter for blanks and delete blank rows.